# vs publish web page using compress js

Tags: javascript, web, gulp

I am using visual studio developing web pages, also using gulp to generate min.js, when I do development I only reference normal js so it is quick i can make change and see it, but when I publish, i will reference the min.js, I wonder, is there a tool to replace the js reference in the page when publishing the website, to refer the min version?

Comment: Does vs mean visual studio? And are you looking for a recommendation for a tool or library, or do you want to know how this can be accomplished using JavaScript? Please edit your question to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on [process html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-processhtml).

When in dev mode reference single or multiple js sources like :

```
<!-- build:js myapp.min.js -->
  <script src="myapp.js"></script> 
<!-- /build -->
```

Then it will be converted as the following when you build :

```
 <script src="myapp.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that is what I want, thx, but one more question, can the destination folder iin gulp command be a parameter? passed in from a job after publishing? because I need to replace the file on the target server (dev, integ, prod), not my local code.

Comment: Yes you can use conditionnal statements, take a look at this article : https://addyosmani.com/blog/environment-specific-builds-with-grunt-gulp-or-broccoli/